# Why is there different elision behaviour between static_cast<T&&> and move<T> in VS 2017

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics

I am struggling to understand the different behavior shown between move and an rvalue cast

given:

```
template <class T> void f1(T param) {  }

struct B { B() = default;  B(B&&) { cout << "Move constructor\n"; } };
void demo()
{

    f1(static_cast<B&&>(B())); // does not call move constructor - constructor is elided
    f1(move(B())); // calls move constructor - no elision
}
```

The move call forces the call to the move constructor, while the static cast does not, and the constructor is apparently elided. This seems strange as the definition of std::move looks very much like a static cast.

Why the different behavior?

**Update:** Cannot be reproduced with gcc. Behavior shown only with MSVC

Comment: `move<B>` - The explicit argument is kinda idiosyncratic, just saying. It's meant to be about deducing the arguments

Comment: what are your observations? What makes you think that move constructor is not called in one case? Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/h5WvEd

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @idclev463035818 Only one print statement produced on VS 2017,  debug mode, x64

Comment: @GonenI if you look at the [CE link](https://godbolt.org/z/h5WvEd) by idclev, you can see that no move constructors are being called, everything is optimized out and only two simple couts are happening.

Comment: @Waqar - You are misrepresenting the assembly and output. Those are empty objects with a user-defined move constructor. The objects may be optimized out, but the behavior is **as-if** they were move constructed. The OP is saying that they managed to observe only a *single* output. That's the wrong behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes right. And In debug mode, the same behaviour is observable. However [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/a1z17E) does indeed call move constructor on one and not the other if I see it correctly.

Comment: @idclev463035818 You cannot reproduce with GCC. With MSVC, there is a difference: https://godbolt.org/z/ccG9ra.

Comment: @DanielLangr indeed. I also managed to get no output at all with MSVC, unfortunately I don't remember how and lost the link

Comment: Possibly wrong copy elision on msvc part.